# glTexImage2D error subtleties between iOS, android- inconsistent documentation

Tags: ios, textures, opengl-es-2.0

So I have this line of code:

`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,shadow_tex_dim.x,shadow_tex_dim.y,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,shadow_texture_data);`

which works fine to establish a depth texture on android (running **OpenGLES2**) (and **OSX**).

When I run it in iOS (iOS 10, also running `OpenGLES2`), `glGetError()` returns `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. (`glGetError()` right before this line returns clean).

Here's the docs for `glTexImage2D`: http://docs.gl/es2/glTexImage2D

Notice that 'internalformat' specifies that the only valid args are "`GL_ALPHA`, `GL_LUMINANCE`, `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA`, `GL_RGB`, `GL_RGBA`", but down in the "examples" section, it shows `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,`GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`, fbo_width, fbo_height, 0,`GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`,`GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, NULL);`
 (which is very similar to my current line, but with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` rather than `GL_FLOAT`.

So, am I allowed to use `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT`? Why does this work on android's `OpenGLES2`, and not iOS's? Where did I get that I should be using `GL_FLOAT` (note that the behavior doesn't seem to change on either iOS *or* android either way...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple support for depth textures would be defined here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_depth_texture.txt

From the documentation there are 2 areas which are relevant:

> Textures with  and  values of DEPTH_COMPONENT
>   refer to a texture that contains depth component data.   is used
>   to determine the number of bits used to specify depth texel values.
>
> A  value of UNSIGNED_SHORT refers to a 16-bit depth value.    A
>    value of UNSIGNED_INT refers to a 32-bit depth value.

and

> The error INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the  and 
>   is DEPTH_COMPONENT and  is not UNSIGNED_SHORT, or UNSIGNED_INT.

This is also interesting: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes

> In OpenGL, all depth values lie in the range [0, 1]. The integer
>   normalization process simply converts this floating-point range into
>   integer values of the appropriate precision. It is the integer value
>   that is stored in the depth buffer.
>
> Typically, 24-bit depth buffers will pad each depth value out to
>   32-bits, so 8-bits per pixel will go unused. However, if you ask for
>   an 8-bit Stencil Buffer along with the depth buffer, the two separate
>   images will generally be combined into a single depth/stencil image.
>   24-bits will be used for depth, and the remaining 8-bits for stencil.
>
> Now that the misconception about depth buffers being floating point is
>   resolved, what is wrong with this call?
>
> `glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT,
>   my pixels);`
>
> Because the depth format is a normalized integer format,
>   the driver will have to use the CPU to convert the normalized integer
>   data into floating-point values. This is slow.

It would appear that Android supports `GL_FLOAT` types for depth texture.